# Reading & Storing input in list, reversing order of list in TCL/TK scripting

Tags: scripting, tcl, tk-toolkit

I am trying to read integers from input then put it into a list.

After, reverse the integers and show the reversed order of that list.

Problem: All of the input is not stored in the list.

I want it to read many integers in one line and store INSTEAD of reading one integer per line.

code:

```
#! /bin/env tclsh

set l1 {}

while 1 {

   # reads input
   set data [gets stdin]  

                          # issue (reads only once per line)

                          # issue (want to make it read many integers in 1 line)

   if {[eof stdin] || [scan $data "%d" myint] != 1} {
       break
   }

   # adds input to list
   lappend l1 $myint  
}

set l2 {}

# make a list 2 with integers in REVERSED order
for {set i [llength $l1]} {$i >= 0} {incr i -1} { 
   lappend l2 [lindex $l1 $i]
}
# print both lists to compare
puts $l1
puts $l2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
% proc getNum {} {
        while 1 {
                set data [gets stdin]
                # Extracting only digits which are whole word
                # i.e.  100 -> accepted
                # i.e.  100a -> Not accepted
                set numbers [regexp -all -inline {\m\d+\M} $data]
                # If the list is empty, then break out of the loop
                if {$numbers eq {}} {break}
                append l1 "$numbers "
        }
        puts "Input : $l1"
        # Using in-built command 'lreverse' to reverse the list elements
        puts "Reversed : [lreverse $l1]"
}
% getNum
109 865 17 36
444 2019 56
8 19 test100 11
a
Input : 109 865 17 36 444 2019 56 8 19 11
Reversed : 11 19 8 56 2019 444 36 17 865 109
%
```

**Reference :** [lreverse](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/lreverse.htm)

Comment: This will accept the input `09` as well, for which you can loop through all the elements from the final list and remove it by simply doing `string trimleft` with the char as `0`.

Comment: To use this i enter tclsh mode and past the code in. Is there a way I can do it as "tclsh t.tcl" and have the input command working?

Comment: Also how would i make able to do getNum{1,2,3,4} in one command? Add list argument to getNum function?

Comment: It would be better to do `lappend l1 {*}$numbers`.

Comment: That does not work "extra characters after close-quote"

Answer (score 0):

This command can read from either the command line arguments or from standard input.

```
proc getNum args {
    if {[llength $args] > 0} {
        set data $args
    } else {
        while {[gets stdin line]} {
            append input $line \n
        }
        set data [split [string trim $input]]
    }
    set numbers [lmap item $data {
        if {[string is integer -strict $item]} {
            set item
        } else {
            break
        }
    }]
    return [lreverse $numbers]
}

% getNum 1 2 3 4
# => 4 3 2 1
% getNum
1 2 3
4 5 6
789
# => 789 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

If there are arguments, it uses those. Otherwise it reads from input, assembling all lines given up to end of file, then splits the text into a list.

Then it checks the data list for items that match the string definition of an integer. All items that check out are added to the result list. As soon as it finds something other than an integer (or when the data list ends) it stops and returns the numbers found in reverse order.

Documentation:
[> (operator)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm),
[append](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/append.htm),
[break](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/break.htm),
[gets](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/gets.htm),
[if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm),
[llength](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/llength.htm),
[lmap (for Tcl 8.5)](http://wiki.tcl.tk/40570),
[lmap](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lmap.htm),
[lreverse](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lreverse.htm),
[proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm),
[return](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/return.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm),
[split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm),
[string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm),
[while](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/while.htm)